# Apple DemoBots project stops at landing page with Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run Apple's example DemoBots (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DemoBots/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179) project using Swift 5, but the app is not loading past the logo splash page.

I've already updated all the Swift3 deprecated methods/properties in the project such as changing the outdated hashValue property to a hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) in the SceneMetadata class, adding isAsynchronous to the SceneOperation class, etc.

If anyone has run into a similar problem running DemoBots with Swift5 please let me know how you solved it.

This is my SceneOperation code:

```
class SceneOperation: Operation {
    // MARK: Types

    /**
        Using the `@objc` prefix exposes this enum to the ObjC runtime,
        allowing the use of `dynamic` on the `state` property.
    */
    @objc enum State: Int {
        /// The `Operation` is ready to begin execution.
        case ready

        /// The `Operation` is executing.
        case executing

        /// The `Operation` has finished executing.
        case finished

        /// The `Operation` has been cancelled.
        case cancelled
    }

    // MARK: Properties

    /// Marking `state` as dynamic allows this property to be key-value observed.
    @objc dynamic var state = State.ready

    // MARK: NSOperation

    override var isReady: Bool {
        return state == .ready && super.isReady
    }

    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        return state == .executing
    }

    override var isFinished: Bool {
        return state == .finished
    }

    override var isCancelled: Bool {
        return state == .cancelled
    }

    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }

    /**
        Add the "state" key to the key value observable properties of `NSOperation`.
    */
    dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsReady() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }

    dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsExecuting() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }

    dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsFinished() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }

    dynamic class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingIsCancelled() -> Set<String> {
        return ["state"]
    }
}
```

The app successfully builds with no runtime or compile time errors/warnings. But it only shows the DemoBots logo and a green particle animation in the background. None of the menu or level scenes are rendered.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, when converting a project to the latest version of Swift, you chose to disable the `@objc` interface. Without this, unfortunately, the project will not work. You can try to switch on `Swift 3 @objc Inference` in build settings.
[image]

Or here you can get worked DemoBot version with supporting Swift 5:
https://github.com/iTehdrew/DemoBot